# Uploading entire folder on google-code

Tags: google-code

I'm trying to upload an entire folder for download to Google code. The exe in the folder relies on other things in the folder, so I can't just upload the individual exe, etc. Does Google code allow this in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just package it as a compressed file, such as a ZIP or RAR (for example). ZIP is the standard as basically everyone in the world can extract zip files.

EDIT: On another topic, not really a programming question. Maybe worth closing due to irrelevancy?